# Java Scanner for ArrayList data

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a do-while loop to get information for an `ArrayList`, but I get this output:

> Please input your number (type a letter to finish): 2
>
> 3
>
> Please input your number (type a letter to finish): 4
>
> Please input your number (type a letter to finish): q

But the operation succeeds and `ArrayList` contains all three numbers (2, 3, 4) as expected even without the prompt having been printed for one of them

```
    do {
        num = getNumber("Please input your number (type a letter to finish): ");
        data.add(num);
    } while (console.hasNextInt());
```

and the method `getNumber`:

```
public static int getNumber(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    return console.nextInt();
}
```

How to I get it to print the prompt for all numbers?

Comment: `} while (console.hasNextInt());` can return true/false only if there is data in `System.in` which can be evaluated. But when you are using `nextInt()` in first iteration you are consuming provided value and there is nothing left for `hasNextInt` to test so it need to wait for new value. Another problem is that you are testing if user provided proper number after already reading it first time (since condition is tested after first iteration). Maybe you are looking for something like: [How to handle infinite loop caused by invalid input using Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3572160)

Answer (score 1):

### Your main problem is calling `nextInt()` before `hasNextInt()`.

You need to do it the [other way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791211/scanner-nextint-and-hasnextint-problems).

Normally, `nextInt()` simply consumes the data waited for using `hasNextInt()`, but if no data has been recieved in this way, `nextInt()` **will itself block**. This is what is causing your problem.

Look at the control flow of your program:

1. `getNumber` is called
2. `prompt` is printed
3. `nextInt()` blocks for input
4. input is given and `getNumber` returns
5. in the do-while loop, `hasNextInt()` blocks for input

   **Here is the problem**, your program waits for input *again* but no new prompt has had a chance to be printed!
6. In the next iteration, `nextInt()` simply consumes the `int` waited for in step 5
7. Now the usual pattern of `hasNextInt()` *before* `nextInt()` has been restored, and so your program behaves as expected from this point on